# Hosts file "type"

Tags: file-association, adware

I am using Windows Vista. The "type" column next to my hosts file in windows explorer says "sAveRabox." This appears to be the name of adware that I recently removed. How can I restore the "type" column to the default name in windows?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the malware was forcing that behavior via registry and the key was left there after removal.

Open the registry editor and go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

See if you have a key there with the name "." (without quotes). If so, delete it, restart and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: You were correct. I have removed the key.